# Association not working in serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, associations

So I have two tables `questions` and `answers`, a question has many answers. I built a serializer to show the answers from questions as such:

Questions serializer:

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :question_type, :is_deleted, :is_editable, :sort, :max_character,
             :min_character, :weighting, :required_languages

  has_many :answers, serializer: AnswerSerializer

  def name
    { en: object.name_en, fr: object.name_fr, es: object.name_es }
  end
```

Answers serializer:

```
class AnswerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :text, :order, :answerId

  def answerId
    object.id
  end

  def text
    { en: object.text_en, fr: object.text_fr, es: object.text_es }
  end
end
```

The problem is that when querying for questions, I don't get answers inside with the has_many association. However, if I include `:answers` as an attribute then the answers do show inside the question. The models for answers and questions are these:

Questions model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Belongs_to associations
  belongs_to :company_department
  belongs_to :question_category

  # Has_many associations
  has_many :join_forms_questions
  has_many :join_answers_forms_questions, through: :join_forms_questions
  has_many :answers
  has_many :join_categories_questions
  has_many :question_categories, through: :join_categories_questions
  has_many :forms, through: :join_forms_questions
end
```

Answers model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Belongs_to associations
  belongs_to :questions
  belongs_to :join_answers_forms_questions
end
```

Anyone has any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: In the attributes of your QuestionSerializer, you have a trailing comma after `:required_languages`. Is that comma actually there in your code? If so, delete it and see if that helps.

Comment: @moveson unfortunately it is not in the code anymore so it is not the issue :(

Comment: Could you show the controller that calls the serializer?